# How to modify each file in directory?

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have file in a single directory and I want to find some tag of words in each file and count them then I go to the next file and ..etc. my problem is how do I know that I finished the first file in order to go to next file. for example:

```
Text1.txt:
do some process 
Text2.txt:
do some process
```

here is my code:

```
directory = os.listdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
for file in directory:   
    with open(file, 'r') as openfile:
        print(file)
        print('\n')
        counter1 = 0
        counter2 = 0
        read_file = openfile.read()
        word_tokens = word_tokenize(read_file)
        for i in word_tokens:
            g = nltk.tag.pos_tag([i])
            for word, tag in g:
                if tag.startswith('JJ'):
                    counter1 = counter1 + 1
                elif tag.startswith('VB'):
                    counter2 = counter2 + 1
                if counter1 > counter2:
                    print("No of Ajdtive = ",counter1)
                elif counter2 > counter1:
                    print("No of verb =",counter2)
```

my problem in my code is , the counter goes to next file and add next value
the output should be as example:
**Text1 has 2 JJ and 1 V:**

```
No of Ajdtive = 2
```

**Text2 has 2V and 1JJ:**

```
No of verb = 2
```

Comment: I get in my output ( No of Ajdtive = 3, No of verb = 3)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any problem with your code, but it is may bad indeted. With the for loop you make sure that each file is processed one after the other. Make sure that the final if-elif branch is within the `with` block!